# bits array to bytes - java

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit

how can I store a sequence of bits in an array of bytes[] ?
in more detail: I have an array

```
byte[] bytes;
```

how will I store individual values (0s and 1s) in a single byte of the array?
I am looking for something like:

```
bit[] bits = new bit[8];
bits[0] = 1;
bits[3] = 1;
bytes[3] = bits[];
```

I hope that makes sense. thanks

Comment: Could you put the 0s and 1s into a `String` and use `Byte.parseByte` with a radix of 2?

Comment: I need to make alterations to the byte sequence every now and then so it wont be a good idea to do it like that as i would have to rebuild the sequence over and over instead of just adding/swapping the new value to the required index posission

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, but it is rather memory inefficient.

Comment: Yes, but OP hasn't told us what his/her input is.  Maybe he/she is reading a file full of 0s and 1s, so already has `String`.  In which case, there's no real cost in memory (at least in Java 6; Java 7 manages memory differently for strings).

Comment: to make it more clear I am using an array of bytes because I am storing binary values of strings in the rest of the indexes. it is just one or two indexes that I need to store bits in them.

Comment: In that case your `Byte.parseByte` would work, but a binary file should be used instead (around 8x less disk space).

Comment: Write yourself a set of functions which treat a byte or int array as a bit array, using shift/mask operations.  `void setBit(array, index, value)`, `bool getBit(array, index)`, and whatever else you feel useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void setBit(int[] array, int index, boolean value) {
    int x = index / 32;
    int y = index % 32;
    int mask = 1 << y;
    if (value) {
        array[x] |= mask;
    }
    else {
        array[x] &= (0xFFFFFFFF ^ mask);
    }
}

boolean getBit(int[] array, int index) {
    int x = index / 32;
    int y = index % 32;
    int mask = 1 << y;
    return (array[x] & mask) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A boolean can be used to represent a bit, but it takes up more memory. You could use [bitwise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operators to save on memory, here is an example:

```
int n = 0;
n |= 1 << 1; // Set bit 1 to true, n is 2
n |= 1 << 3; // Set bit 3 to true, n is 10
bool b0 = n & (1 << 3) > 0; // True
n &= 1 << 3; // Set bit 3 to false, n is 2
bool b1 = n & (1 << 1) > 0; // True
bool b2 = n & (1 << 2) > 0; // False
bool b3 = n & (1 << 3) > 0; // False
```

Comment: You could replace each `Math.pow` with `1 << something`

Comment: It is more a matter of memory in my case than a matter of true & false so a Boolean wont work for me..

Comment: Bitwise operators will be the most memory efficient way possible.